# How would I go about replacing usage of the "loop" function in Common Lisp without introducing new dependencies?

Tags: common-lisp

It seems that the loop function in Common Lisp goes against the regular syntax and style of the rest of the language. What functions or tricks can I use to avoid using loop without introducing more dependencies?

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow for actual programming problems. Best with code and a problem description.

Also feel free to use LOOP. Iterative loops are not against Common Lisp 'style'.

Comment: This question is very unclear and not answerable in it's current state.  If the usage of a loop is necessary or not, and strategies to avoid using a loop vary greatly depending on what the code is meant to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

Learn the other looping forms: `do`,`do*`, `dotimes`, `dolist`, `map`, `mapcar`, `mapcon`, `maplist`, `mapc`, `mapl`, `reduce`, ….

There are some things very conveniently expressed as `loop` forms, however, so don't be too religious.  Examples:

```
(loop :repeat n :do (stuff))

(loop :for line := (read-line in nil)
      :while line
      :do (stuffle line))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) functions and [`reduce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm) ought to solve many problems. If you think it's a style thing with `loop` you may want to try [Iterate](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) where higher order functions don't suffice.

**EDIT**
Why would you avoid dependencies? Using available code is better than avoiding it and do more work. Make install instructions on how to install dependencies. Iterate has [quicklisp support](https://www.quicklisp.org/), which is like a packet manager for lisp packages. I only had to evaluate `(ql:quickload "iterate")`
to get it installed and loaded. (Of course you need to install quicklisp for it to work)